# Undownvote a question or answer

Tags: discussion

If I accidentally downvoted an answer or question, it became -1. When I undownvote it, it becomes 1, not 0. Why?

Comment: Because you upvoted. Just press the downvote button again to undo.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: May be on the same time, some other user may upvote the answer, so when you undo or upvote to the answer, its looks like the upvote count as `1`. But the `1` is display due to the other user's upvote.

Comment: Upvote is **not** undoing of a downvote. It's, well, an upvote. And if you did click the downvote again, @Arulkumar answer is probably the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default when you downvote and undownvote to the answer/question, the count will be same as the previous count only.

May be on the same time, some other user may upvote the answer/question, so when you undo or updownvote to the answer/question, its looks like the vote count is as `1`. But the `1` is display due to the other user's upvote.